# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jieba'

Tags: python, pycharm

When I run my code on Pycharm,it works well.However,when I use "python [my_code_file_name].py" to run code on windows shell,the system says that no module found to run,could anyone help me to solve this?Thanks.

the project intepreter path is:

> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe

when I search some methods,I have tried this to add in my code:

```
import sys

sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python.exe")
```

but still not working.

besides,I run my code on Pycharm,it works well.

and when I run "python [my_code_file_name].py" on windows shell,it shows the message below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import jieba.analyse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jieba'
```

and my project works not on virtual environment,the intepreter is the package which I downloaded from python official website and manually installed on my computer.

Comment: You may have multiple versions of Python installed. When you run `where python` in the windows shell does it match the interpreter that PyCharm is using?

Comment: @IainShelvington when I run `where python`,it shows the python intepreter path is `C:\Python37\python.exe`,not the same as my project intepreter path.

Comment: You need to run the correct interpreter, you can do this by using the full path (in the question above) to the interpreter, set the `PATH` environment variable to look in the directory for your interpreter first, uninstall the other versions of Python... There are lots of ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the same python that's being used by your project interpreter? Try

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe [my_code_file_name].py
```

Or you could modify system variables to prefer executables in `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32`, then when your system searches for `python` it'll hit that directory first. Is that a virtual environment? There may be a way to activate that environment so that you don't have to type the full path of the executable or modify system variables yourself.

Your attempt to modify your sys.path isn't correct; sys.path entries should point to a directory containing python module, not to a python executable. You should have done this:

```
sys.path.append("C:\\path\\to\\the\\module\\that\\you\\want")
```

where `C:\path\to\the\module\that\you\want\jieba` would be the directory containing the `jieba` module (e.g. you point your path to the parent directory). Your custom python path looks like you may have several versions of python installed on the system, so simply modifying your sys.path probably won't work if your default python is a different version from your project's python. I wouldn't recommend doing that. Ideally, activate the environment if possible, or invoke whichever executable that you want directly.

Comment: when I run `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe [my_code_file_name].py`,it works well,thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Looks like you've definitely got multiple versions of python installed on your system, then. Would you mind accepting and upvoting my answer?